# java jpa retrieve List<String[]>

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following code, to get possible list of array strings.

after my query executes, i have problems retrieving the data.
i get  class cast exception error `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;`

```
List<String[]> branchList= repoFactory.getBranchRepo().searchByBranchCodeorNameLike(branchSearchCriteria, Boolean.TRUE);
String[]  t= branchList.get(0); // error line


//in my jpa repo class
@Query("SELECT distinct b.branchName,b.branchCode FROM Branch b WHERE (b.branchName like %:branchSearchName% OR b.branchCode like %:branchSearchName%) AND b.active=:active")
List<String[]> searchByBranchCodeorNameLike(@Param("branchSearchName") String branchSearchName, @Param("active") Boolean active);
```

how do i resolve this error. thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're expecting the generic type info (String[]) to be present when calling get(), but it isn't. Generic types are present only during compile time (not runtime). I'm not sure the right fix, need to see more code.

Comment: when query is run in  sql developer, i get 2 coloumns of string values,

Comment: What happens if you do something like this, one line before the error: `System.out.println(branchList.get(0).getClass())`. That should shed some light on what’s happening.

Comment: branchList.get(0).getClass() throws same class cast exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify the select clause like you did, the return value is a `List<Object[]>`. That's why you have `ClassCastException`.

Hibernate is not going to check if each columns has the same type so that it can be included in a `String[]`. And Java doesn't cast the whole array to a different type (even if `String[]` would work in this  case).

You could define an interface:

```
public insterface BranchCode {
    String getBranchName();
    String getBranchCode();
}
```

And then use it as the returned list type:

```
@Query(...)
List<BranchCode> searchByBranchCodeorNameLike(..);
```

Or, you can return a `List<Object[]>` and cast the single values when you need them:

```
List<Object[]> result = repo.searchByBranchCodeorNameLike(...);
for (Object[] row : result) {
   String branchName = (String) row[0];
   String branchCode = (String) row[1];
   ...
}
```